# How to resolve jquery version not less than 4.00

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I have some libraries, but when i try to inspect or debug i always get this annoying misconflict jquery libraries. The problem is stating must use latest of Bootstrap version 4.00 not less. This happens every time i want to use Datepicker

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkbox").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  }).val()
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<input type='text' id='checkbox' />
```

I am now getting a warning here yet not all my bootstrap buttons now seem to be working, what could i be missing or did?

Comment: I've attempted to convert to a snippet to see the actual error (please include the exact wording) - but you're linking to `~/scripts/bootstrap.js` - so we can't tell which version of bootstrap you're trying to load.

Comment: The requirements to use datepicker are: 
Bootstrap 2.0.4+ and jQuery 1.7.1+. Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @freedomn, i am using version 3.4.1

Comment: So the error is `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4` - the **relevant part is jquery 1.9.1** as the *minimum* (not "not less than 4")

Comment: bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: @freedomn yes thats the error

Comment: So, change your jquery 1.9.1?

Comment: must it be 1.9.1? i need to use correct one so can solve this library mismatch

Comment: No, but it must be at 1.9.1 or higher, and also less than 4.0; tbh I'm not sure what you're not getting here.  It could be latest 3.5.1 *for the bootstrap requirement* - whether the rest of your site works is another matter as there are a number of changes between v1 and v3.

Comment: @freedom i have used 1.9.1, but no error

Comment: I have shown team my new changes, but now my functionality is not working and yet no error after i put jquery.1.91.1. What am i missing team?